# Find the sum of five numbers in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment to write a program that reads in five whole numbers from the user. The program will calculate and output
the following statistics about the five numbers:
The sum of all of the positive numbers (greater than zero),
The sum of all of the non-positive numbers (less than or equal to zero),
The sum of all five numbers,
The average of all of the positive numbers (greater than zero),
The average of all of the non-positive numbers (less than or equal to zero),
and the average of all five numbers.

I got some help from my professor on the averages but I'm not sure about finding the total sum of all five numbers. Any advice/help appreciated!

Here's my code so far:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class PA2b {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("Enter five whole numbers: ");
       String[] nums = input.nextLine().split(" ");
       int[] numbers = new int[5];
       int positiveCount = 0;
       int countNegative = 0;
       int sumPositive = 0;
       int sumNegative = 0;
       int overallSum = 0;

       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

           int number = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
           numbers[i] = number;
           if (number > 0) {
               positiveCount++;
               sumPositive += number;
           } else {
               countNegative++;
               sumNegative += number; 
           }
       }

       if (positiveCount == 1) {
           System.out.println("The sum of the " + positiveCount + " non-positive numbers: " + sumPositive);
       } else {
           System.out.println("The sum of the " + positiveCount + " positive numbers: " + sumPositive);
       }
       if (countNegative == 1) {
           System.out.println("The sum of the " + countNegative + " negative number: " + sumNegative);
       } else {
           System.out.println("The sum of the " + countNegative + " negative numbers: " + sumNegative);
       }
       if (overallSum == 1) {
           System.out.println("The sum of the " + positiveCount + " non-positive numbers: " + sumPositive);
       }
       double averagePositive = 0.00;
       double averageNegative = 0.00;
       double averageAll = 0.00;
       
       if (positiveCount > 0) {
           averagePositive = (double) sumPositive / positiveCount;
       }
       if (positiveCount > 0) {
           averageNegative = (double) sumNegative / countNegative;
       }
       averageAll = (double) (sumNegative + sumPositive) / 5;

       if (positiveCount == 1) {
           System.out.println("The average of the " + positiveCount + " positive number: " + averagePositive);
       } else {
           System.out.println("The average of the " + positiveCount + " positive numbers: " + averagePositive);
       }
       if (positiveCount == 1) {
           System.out.println("The average of the " + countNegative + " negative number: " + averageNegative);
       } else {
           System.out.println("The average of the " + countNegative + " negative numbers: " + averageNegative);
       }

       System.out.println("The average of the 5 numbers: " + averageAll);

   }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you v=have already calculated the total sum of all five numbers in your code which is (sumNegative + sumPositive)

Comment: Ahhh, I see! Didn't realize that as it was where I got help. Thank you!

Comment: Or you add `number` in each iteration of that for loop to `overallSum`. After it looped over all numbers it will have created the sum of all numbers. Just like `sumPositive` or `sumNegative` but regardless positive / negative.

Comment: Awesome thanks!